# MailCompositionService quit unexpectedly ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I am new to this,

I have this code in my viewController,

```
- (void)sendMail:(id)sender {
    NSArray *to = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"rayjada11@gmail.com", nil];

    mailComposer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    mailComposer.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    [mailComposer setToRecipients:to];
    [mailComposer setSubject:@"Test Mail"];
    [mailComposer setMessageBody:@"Testing message body" isHTML:NO];
    [self presentModalViewController:mailComposer animated:YES];
}



#pragma mark - mail compose delegate
-(void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error {
    if(result) {
        NSLog(@"Result = %d", result);
    }
    if(error) {
        NSLog(@"Error = %@", error);
    }
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

But when I click send button in my controller, I am getting error like,

> 2016-09-05 14:55:24.488 mailDemo[1276:104171]
>   viewServiceDidTerminateWithError: Error
>   Domain=_UIViewServiceInterfaceErrorDomain Code=3 "(null)"
>   UserInfo={Message=Service Connection Interrupted} 2016-09-05
>   14:55:24.989 mailDemo[1276:104171] Trying to dismiss the presentation
>   controller while transitioning already.
>   (<_UIFullscreenPresentationController: 0x7fe35b52d2a0>) 2016-09-05
>   14:55:24.991 mailDemo[1276:104171] transitionViewForCurrentTransition
>   is not set, presentation controller was dismissed during the
>   presentation? (<_UIFullscreenPresentationController: 0x7fe35b52d2a0>)

What is the issue?

Comment: Please check your device login in mail in setting app.

Comment: present after a check that it can present mail compose controller or not and test in device with mail configured in settings.

Comment: I am testing it in simulator. @BhadreshKathiriya

Comment: Thanks, I think MFMailComposeViewController not working in simulator. @M.K.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code.`MFMailComposeViewController` is not work for simulator, Try same code in real device.

Comment: Thanks, I think MFMailComposeViewController not working in simulator. @ajay_nasa

Comment: No worries, Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

simulator doesn't supported method and device doesn't login in mail that this method nothing response.

replace this method ::

```
- (void)sendMail:(id)sender {


    if (![MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
        NSLog(@"Mail services are not available.");
        return;
    }
    else{
            NSArray *to = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"rayjada11@gmail.com", nil];

            mailComposer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
            mailComposer.mailComposeDelegate = self;
            [mailComposer setToRecipients:to];
            [mailComposer setSubject:@"Test Mail"];
            [mailComposer setMessageBody:@"Testing message body" isHTML:NO];
            [self presentModalViewController:mailComposer animated:YES];
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

MFMailComposeViewController does  not work for simulators. If you try  the same code in real device, it will work. There is nothing wrong with your code.